# Unable to run java code in intelliJ and can't resolve build.gradle symbols

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I got a java project that has exercises in it. But for some reason i'm unable to run any code. i cloned the project and didn't do anything else with it. It doesn't contain a run configuration (this might be the problem), but i'm unsure how to properly set one up. i set up SDK version 10.0.2. my build.gradle is also acting up, intelliJ can't resolve any symbols, e.g. group, version,buildscript etc.

java file that i'm trying to run: https://gyazo.com/5f75ee5ea94632b07919a9deef86c6c4
(it doesn't give me an option to run the file, even when i rightclick, there is no run option)

gradle:
https://gyazo.com/4ecbc633e20d2e80f367a30a102cb4fa
(can't resolve any symbols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by linking the gradle project, apparently it wasn't linked. IntelliJ event log gave me the option to link it.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on one of your project files and finding something like "Synchronize StartingJava.java"

Comment: i tried this, it gives a small message: "Synchronize 'Startingjava.java' completed successfull."  But nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

To [open the Gradle project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import_project_start) use File | New | **Project from Existing Sources** or **Open** actions and choose main `build.gradle` file to import from. IDE will automatically set up the project structure and dependencies.